# rsync files newer than 1 week

Tags: linux, rsync

I want to run rsync on server A to copy all files from Server B when they are newer than 7 days.

```
find . -mtime -7
```

I don't want to delete the files on Server B.

Comment: b) how often do you run rsync?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

This should get you underway in a solid way

```
rsync -RDa0P \
    --files-from=<(find sourcedir/./ -mtime -7 -print0) \
    . user@B:targetdir/
```

This copies device nodes, permissions, timestamps. I'm pretty sure the -H option won't be accurate with --files-from

Comment: To set that as a remote filter: `rsync -avn --files-from=<(ssh user@A 'find /path/on/A/ -mtime -7 -type f -exec basename {} \;') user@A:/path/on/A/ user@B:targetdir`

Comment: I want to add a correction for cybertoast's comment. Perhaps the context on his different from mine but I was trying to simple extract files from a remote server given the time criteria. So, server A is my destination and server B is my source, then: rsync -avn --files-from=<(ssh user@A 'find /path/on/A/ -mtime -7 -type f -exec basename {} \;') user@B:/ /path/in/server/A  Notice there's only a leading / for source. The --files-from takes care of the relative path for you. If you have doubts use man rsync and see the --files-from section.

Comment: @cybertoast What does `basename` mean in your command? Can you explain please?

Comment: @KematRochi - "basename, dirname -- return filename or directory portion of pathname". Hope that helps.

Comment: @KematRochi Yeah, I don't see the point of `basename`. What if there are multiple, identically named files with different modification times? This command as it stands will transfer them all, regardless of their modification times.

Comment: find returns the relative path, then the -basename {} turns the output into absolute paths

Comment: @CodeSlicer correct; I think my solution subtly hinges on the special meaning of `/./` in rsync when using `-R` (***not*** `-r`). Does that answer your concern?

Answer (score 7):

I wrote this script based on cybertoast's comment to sync from a remote server to local.

You can call the script with `./script.sh 3` or `./script.sh 3 dry` for a dry run.

```
#!/bin/bash
TIME=$1
DRYRUN=$2

if [[ -z $TIME ]]; then
  echo "Error: no time argument."
  echo "Please enter the number of days to sync."
  exit 1
fi

if [[ $DRYRUN = "dry" ]]; then
  DRYRUNCMD="--dry-run"
  echo "Dry run initiated..."
fi

rsync -avz $DRYRUNCMD --files-from=<(ssh \
    user@remote "find path/to/data/ \
    -mtime -$TIME ! -name *.mkv -type f \
    -exec ls $(basename {}) \;") \
  user@remote:. .
```