# Copy 1-hour-old files from another machine

Tags: bash, scp

I have this part in my script where I would copy files from another machine to the current machine running.

`scp user@samplemachine:/home/user/test/* /home/user/test`

But then I should only copy files created 1 hour ago. How can I achieve this? Please help me with this. Thanks

Comment: Do look at this too: http://superuser.com/questions/297342/rsync-files-newer-than-1-week

Answer (score 2):

The `scp` command does not offer any filtering by modification time or date. But since you have access to `scp` you also have access via `ssh` - I assume. If not than the following won't help you.

Before actually copying files, you could find out which files have a modification date of more than one hour.

```
for i in `find <location> -name <filename> -type f -mmin +60`
do
    scp $i <user>@<destination server>:/<destination directory>/
done
```

The option you are looking for:

```
-mmin n
    File's data was last modified n minutes ago.
```

The `+` before the number of minutes tells `find` to look for files modified 60 and more minutes ago. `-` would find 60 and less minutes.

This script would be run on the remote machine through `ssh` and will push files to a destionation machine.